# beautiful soup extracting table data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i'm noob to bs4. i read some tutorials and tried some simple examples.
i want to extract data from tables and i can't do it properly.

this is the html_source:

```
<table class="tborder" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 0px" id="post45894054">
<tr>
<td>
<div class="alt2" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 0px; padding:5px; border:2px groove">
<div class="smallfont"><em>
<br />
Good news today.
</em></div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i would like to extract the 'Good news today'

i tried that code, but it didn't worked as i expected:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

base_url = "some url"
html_page = urllib2.urlopen(base_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
print soup
tables = soup.select("table .alt2 .smallfont br")

print tables
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<table class="tborder" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 0px" id="post45894054">
<tr>
<td>
<div class="alt2" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 0px; padding:5px; border:2px groove">
<div class="smallfont"><em>
<br />
Good news today.
</em></div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table> """)

print(soup.find("table",attrs={"class":"tborder"}).text.strip())
Good news today.

print(soup.find(attrs={"class":"smallfont"}).text.strip())
Good news today.
```

Comment: @omri_saadon, no prob there are lots of different ways  that is just a couple

Comment: how can i change it to findall? because when i change it to findall i get an exception "'NoneType' object is not callable" @Padraic Cunningham

Comment: why do you need findall?

Comment: in case i have a lot of tables and not just one

Comment: @omri_saadon but all the tables will have to have the same structure or it will fail. Do you have an example url?

Comment: of course.. that's the idea :) all tables will be the same

Comment: well then first find all tables then iterate over that list and use one of the two examples in my  answer t extract the text